# Csv hebrew text not in good order

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, right-to-left

I am trying to import csv file to use the data in my php project to insert them in mysql database. The problem is that my csv file contains one column woth hebrew character. This csv converted from xls file. 
The problem is that when i open the file with excel i have correct display, like that

[image: text in excel]

But when i am trying to use the csv file. I have a problem of order

פרקט תלת שכבתי אלון 189x15/4 גרי  ישן מעושן גימור שמן UV

Somebody know how to resolve this problem thanks!

The problem is not in my php script.  My php script is all right. But the problem is that the xcel cell format not correspond when i use it in csv.

The problem is when an English word or number is mixed in with the text:

Example:
English: 
“Can we improve the health of patients by giving them Aspirin?” 
Hebrew: 
“[Hebrew translated text] Aspirin?” 
This is displayed as:
Aspirin [Hebrew translated text]?

Hopefully I explained the issue enough. It is a little confusing so if I need clarify more, please let me know.

Any help or experience is appreciated?

Comment: What schema are you importing into?

Comment: After converting in csv i convert it to json with online tool to use in php project to insert data in mysql database

Comment: This is a MySQL problem and not a JSON problem, or is it a JSON problem?

Comment: The problem is before json and before mysql. In csv i have a wrong parsing and in json i receive from csv, so all is with error

Comment: I have the same problem when i copy ctrl+c from excel to some another editor like word i have the same problem

Comment: It's really not clear where your problem is based on your description. If you're loading it into MySQL do you have the command used? The column type you're trying to import into could be wrong.

Comment: I add precision in my question

Comment: how did an html solution work for you, I thought you had a csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an RTL language speaker, I think I can be of help.

It all depends on the text direction the UI is using. Most of the application uses LTR (Left-to-Right) for text direction by default. If you are using MySQL Workbench to see the values stored in the column, MySQL Workbench uses LTR direction as well. That's why you will see the wrong order problem when you have bi-directional (text mixed with numbers) text.

Keep in mind, that CSV is merely a UTF-8 plain text, which means the text is style-less and direction-less. You need only to set your HTML direction to RTL. See example below:

```html
<h3>Wrong LTR Direction</h3>
<p dir="ltr">פרקט תלת שכבתי אלון 189x15/4 גרי ישן מעושן גימור שמן UV</p>

<h3>Correct RTL Direction</h3>
<p dir="rtl">פרקט תלת שכבתי אלון 189x15/4 גרי ישן מעושן גימור שמן UV</p>
```

Salam :)

Comment: who said anything about html though?

Comment: @barlop Nobody... It is just an example to demonstrate using LTR while using RTL language. You can do the same thing using notepad changing the text direction between LTR and RTL.

Comment: but how does an example to demonstrate how in one environment, html, you can get  RTL, when he mentioned nothing of that environment, similarly, saying it can be done in notepad, when he didn't say his problem is how to do it in notepad .. As an example, of a mysql related environment where the problem exists - (and that would be relevant given his tag of mysql)   try typing or copy/pasting hebrew or arabic into cmd.exe or the mysql console.  This can be done by adding and setting the font to courier new.  It comes out LTR as does a select query on a file with hebrew.

Comment: @barlop this is not an example for 'how to fix it'. This is an example for 'how it works'. In short, you can call it a bug in MySQL Workbench because it always sets the column - (the one you see in the result section not how it is stored) - direction to LTR regardless of its content. LTR direction UI +  mixed text = wrong format

Comment: @Aboodz did the questioner give the impression that he did not understand the concept of a language being RTL?